# Multiple text in Augmented Reality in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am making an augmented reality App to demonstrate the options in MacBook  and I used the [Vuforia SDK](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Getting-Started-with-Vuforia-for-iOS-Development.html).

Here is my problem:

1) I tried with [Vuforia Sample Core Feature](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples) and I used Image Targets.  In Image targets it gives only one image at a time. I attached the output in below mentioned image.

[image]
[image]

2) My expectation is to show multiple text or image while capturing the real MacBook like below mentioned image.

[image]

Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: I fail to understand what your problem is exactly? Just add more text objects to your image target object...

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia iOS SDK is using OpenGL ES loading 3D object，which's unfriendly to use.

You can use Scenekit, put your objects in a scene, set a rectangle node, put the model in four corners of a rectangle.When ImageTrack is success, load your scene.

How to use SceneKit in Vuforia? check this:https://github.com/yshrkt/VuforiaSampleSwift

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will check and get back to you ChokWah

Comment: Hi ChokWah, I tried it. But i couldn't show all the text in single capture. It will come like first 2 images I mentioned in Question.